# how do you find all upd connections a remote server has?

Tags: udp

Given an IP address of a server connecting to unknown clients via UDP, is it possible to find the IP address of all connected sessions on that server?

I do not have access to the server, I would like to find out who is connecting to it.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a security question. This is either a networking question or an OS question.

Comment: In UDP, there is no concept of "connected" or "session" at that layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by having the IP of a server it is not possible to find out which connections the server has to other systems. To get this information one either need to have access to the server itself or to some system which is in the path of the traffic and the ability to capture traffic there, have a look at the firewall states or similar.